# How to install OpenGL in Yocto to resolve "No GL implementation is available" error

Tags: linux, flutter, opengl, yocto, mesa

I'm encountering an issue when running an application on my Yocto-based system, and I'm getting the error message: `Failed to start Flutter renderer: No GL implementation is available.` Additionally, when I check the existence of the 'gtk+-3.0' package using `pkg-config`, it shows that the 'gl' package is not found in the search path and suggests adding the directory containing 'gl.pc' to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.

```
root@apalis-imx8-07013820:/usr/lib/pkgconfig# pkg-config --exists --print-errors 'gtk+-3.0'
Package gl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gl', required by 'epoxy', not found
```

I have already added the 'mesa' package to my local.conf, but it seems that 'gl.pc' is not present in the '/usr/lib/pkgconfig' directory. When I open the 'epoxy.pc' file, it shows the following content:

```
prefix=/usr
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

epoxy_has_glx=1
epoxy_has_egl=1
epoxy_has_wgl=0

Name: epoxy
Description: GL dispatch library
Version: 1.5.10
Requires.private: x11, egl, gl egl
Libs: -L${libdir} -lepoxy
Libs.private: -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly install OpenGL or resolve the `No GL implementation is available`"error in Yocto. Additionally, I'd like to know how to ensure that 'gl.pc' is available in the '/usr/lib/pkgconfig' directory. Thank you for your help!

Tried to install OpenGL in Yocto. Expected success, got "No GL implementation" error.

Answer (score 0):

You asked two questions here, one for `No GL implementation..` and one for `Package gl not found ...`.

If you assume that the presence of `gl.pc` will solve the first question, then:

`/usr/lib/pkgconfig/gl.pc` is provided by `libgl-mesa-dev`.

Check:

```
oe-pkgdata-util find-path /usr/lib/pkgdata/gl.pc
```

If you just want `gl.pc` in your image, just add that package:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " libgl-mesa-dev"
```

Comment: This is going to be software OpenGL without GPU usage, Check https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/How-to-generate-SDK-for-imx6dl-with-OpenGL-using-Yocto/m-p/418106#M62940

Comment: Hi @talel-belhadjsalem, 

And when i add the **libgl-mesa-dev** package, i got the gl.pc. 
But the issue still persist when running the application.
`
(sample:3249): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 06:27:15.210: gdk_window_get_state: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed

** (sample:3249): WARNING **: 06:27:15.221: Failed to start Flutter renderer: No GL implementation is available
`
I create a sample gtk3 application in c and i got it worked without any issue.

Comment: I answered that because it is mentioned in your question. I also mentioned that it is not assumed to fix the `No GL` issue. If this helped you mark it as solution, or I will try to check the other part of question for you.

Comment: Hi @TalelBELHADJSALEM , Please help to check the  **'No GL implementation'** error.